# Invertibility of $T:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R_2[X]$ and determinant

Tags: linear-algebra

In my course, it's written that determinant only apply for operator, i.e. application from a space into it self. I have to admit that I never really consider this detail and I applied it for ever application from $V\to W$ when $V$ and $W$ has same finite dimension. I had a test last week that whas to prove invertibility of $T: \mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R_2[X]$ defined as $$T(a,b,c)=b+(a+b)x+cx^2.$$
What I did is I computed $$[T]_{EB}=\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0\\1&1&0\\ 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$$
where $B$ and $E$ are the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$ and $\mathbb R_2[X]$, and then I said that $$\det([T]_{EB})=-1\neq 0,$$
and thus I had mark 0/10. The teacher said that determinant are only defined for endomorphism.

But my way is correct no ? Since $\mathbb R_2[X]$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb R^3$. I denote $S$ such a morphism s.t. $S(1,0,0)=1$, $S(0,1,0)=x$ and $S(0,0,1)=x^2$. Set $K:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R^3$ s.t. $(a,b,c)=(b,a+b,c)$ So $T=S\circ K$ where $S$ is an isomorphism, and in fact $[K]_{BB}=[T]_{EB}$. Then $\det([K]_{BB})=-1$ and thus $K$ is invertible, therfore, $T$ is the composition of two isomorphism and thus is invertible.

But since such an argument is ALWAYS working, I can use the determinant to prove that $T\in L(V,W)$ where $\dim V=\dim W$ is invertible or not, no ?

So do I really have $0$ point at this exercise ?

Comment: The determinant is defined for a square matrix (with entries from a commutative ring, if you want a certain amount of generality).  Even to define the "determinant" in connection with a map of a linear transformation one needs to make choices of ordered basis, so that the transformation can be represented by a square matrix.  Now for a map from a finite dimensional vector space to itself, using the same ordered basis for both sides of the transformation, the determinant works out the same for every choice of basis.  So something can be said about your Question.

Comment: @hardmath In any case the transformation is invertible, it seems not correct to give 0/10 to me.

Comment: Strange to have 0 pts. I agree that $\det(T)$ is well defined for operator only, but the determinant is well defined for any square matrix, and one can prove that $T$ is invertible $\iff$ there is basis $B_V$ (of $V$) and $B_W$ (of $W$) s.t. $\det(T)_{B_WB_V}\neq 0$. Moreover, if such a result hold then $\det(T)_{BB'}\neq 0$ for all basis B of $V$ and all basis $B'$ of $W$.

Comment: @Peter Please recall that if the OP is solved you can evaluate to accept an answer among the given, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you are correct, the determinat is $-1$ and the transformation is of course invertible. I don't think you deserved $0/10$.

Maybe there is some confusion in the input or in the presentation of the result?

Comment: Thank you :) The teacher insist on the fact that the determinant can be used only for operator, i.e. application from $V\to V$, and that taken the determinant of an application $V\to W$ if $V\neq W$ doesn't make any sense... (It's what he said). Do you agree with that ?

Comment: @Peter I've just noted te comment by hardmath and I'm thinking about that. In any case the transformation is invertible and you do not deserve a 0/10.

Comment: @Peter Maybe your professor want that you determine the invertibility by rank concept and without referring to the determinant.

Comment: Well, IMO it depends on what kind of _test_ it is. If it is a test that stresses on perfect handling of concepts taught by _the teacher_, then 0/10 is fine, since the approach taken by OP exposits a failure in remembering how his teacher defined determinant. But if it is a math exam, 0/10 seems not to be a fair mark.